# Jmeter - How to fix - Non HTTP response code: java.net.NoRouteToHostException... (Address not available)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am performing a JMeter test and I am receiving the following error in my HTML report & CSV.

`Non HTTP response code: java.net.NoRouteToHostException/Non HTTP response message: Can't assign requested address (Address not available)`

Note 1: I am also not reserving any server logs for the above error. so, not sure whether it is really an error or is there something to do with the JMeter itself.

Note 2: I have also seen some couple of feeds regarding this issue. but, thats seems to be too old and it doesn't help me really.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [exception description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html)

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

Most probably this is your server issue like:

- [you exceeded the maximum range of connections from one machine to a specific service on the remote machine](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html)
- or requests are blocked by the [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
- or [sockets are not being re-used and hang in TIME_WAIT state](http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/)
- etc.

So this is definitely indicates the error in the application under test or middleware configuration, I would recommend reporting it as a bug. Going forward make sure to monitor the application under test resources (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap, etc.) in order to be able to correlate the increasing load with the resources consumption, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test), the tool you should be looking for to track the number of open connections is [`netstat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat)

Comment: > or sockets are not being re-used and hang in TIME_WAIT state - 

For anyone interest, since the original URL has been moved, here is the archived version of the URL

https://web.archive.org/web/20160822061702/http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/